# Каковы отличительные признаки стихотворной формы "мадригал"?

Tags: литература, поэзия

Прочитала интересную статью о мадригале, но так и не поняла, **в чем его особенность.** Это только определенная тема и форма стиха или **что-то "еще"?** Вот это "еще" меня особенно интересует.

**И вопрос:** Можно ли сейчас написать современный мадригал, чтобы окружающие **сразу узнали эту форму**? (Может быть, кто-нибудь напишет для примера.) Или это невозможно?

Есть ли вообще примеры мадригалов в современной поэзии? Почему устарела эта форма и можно ли ее возродить?

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

**Это Пушкин**

*О вы, которые любовью не горели,

Взгляните на нее – узнаете любовь.

О вы, которые уж сердцем охладели,

Взгляните на нее: полюбите вы вновь.*

«Мадригал М…ой», А. С. Пушкин.

**А это Пушкин о мадригале:**

*Бывало, нежные поэты

В надежде славы и похвал

Точили тонкий мадригал

Иль остроумные куплеты...

Когда блистательная дама

Мне свой in quarto подает,

И дрожь, и злость меня берет,

И шевелится эпиграмма

Во глубине моей души,

А мадригалы им пиши!*

https://pishi-stihi.ru/madrigal.html
https://studopedia.ru/1_7209_ot-madrigala-k-epitalame.html

Comment: https://www.culture.ru/s/slovo-dnya/madrigal/

Comment: Там  рассказано о темах и формах (это я уже читала в других статьях), но не названы отличительные признаки. Можете написать 4 строки на современную тему, чтобы было понятно, что это мадригал.  Дело-то, наверное, нехитрое. Знания же нужны не умозрительно-описательные, а практического характера.  Мне кажется, что человек что-то знает только тогда, когда может применит это в жизни.

Comment: в вашей первой статье сказано, что "изначально так называли музыкальную форму", но это неверно. В моей статье более точные сведения. Отличительных признаков мадригала как стихотворного жанра я не знаю (не думаю, что они вообще есть).

Comment: Я вообще-то тоже слышала, что это музыкальный термин (может, он действительно ошибочный), но мне ближе тема поэзии. А если отличительных черт нет, то зачем вообще выделять этот жанр? Соответственно, можно сделать вывод, что они все-таки должны быть.  Вот мне и захотелось  лучше понять эту форму.  А все описания и рассуждения – это хождение вокруг да около, пока не попробуешь применить их на практике.

Comment: я не пробовал написать, к примеру, симфонию, но почему-то мне кажется, что могу описать этот жанр довольно точно и рассуждать о нём довольно предметно.

Comment: Написать четверостишие – это не симфонию сочинить., а вот рисование и стихосложение раньше входили в обязательное образование, даже в античные времена.  У Акунина его герой любил, к примеру, писать лимерики на все случаи своей жизни, они его морально поддерживали. (Ли́мерик — стихотворный жанр английского происхождения, пятистишие абсурдистского содержания.)